# .htaccess mod_rewrites on trailing slash

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having trouble finding the source of this seemingly mod_rewrite issue in my `.htaccess` for a multi-site WordPress installation.

The problem is that when I try to type a page directly into the address bar (e.g. `example.com/page`), it redirects me to the `wp-login.php` script/page.

If I load `example.com` first, then type in the trailing slash and page (e.g. `example.com` first, then add `/page` and hit enter), it works.

I have handed this problem over to my web hosting team, and they were not able to resolve the issue. I also worked in web-hosting before.

The site is currently not the "primary domain", but does have all of its files in a sub-dir of the main root (eg. `parent/public_html/subdir`), but its in its own domain and document root. This is site 1, blog 2 (in `wp-config.php` and DB).

The WordPress multi-site install loads everything else fine.

Here's my `.htaccess`:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##


RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.tld$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.tld$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.tld/$1 [R,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]


# Wordfence WAF
<Files ".user.ini">
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>

# END Wordfence WAF
```

Comment: Where is this `.htaccess` file? Do you have any other `.htaccess` files? This doesn't sound like a mod_rewrite/`.htaccess` issue. There's certainly nothing in the `.htaccess` file you have posted that could trigger a redirect to `wp-login.php`. That is something that WordPress would do in the application code.

Comment: There is a .htaccess in this subdirectory, and also in the parent. The parent mainly handles expires and caching.

I am serious though, it's only letting me type the url to the page directly after I load the homepage, and without typing the URL in full again (e.g. only by adding on to the existing URL).

Comment: And if you immediately then request `/anotherpage` - what happens? Does that work? At what point do you need to go back to requesting the bare domain? There must be something different in the requests - examine the HTTP request headers that are being sent. On the initial request there may be no session/cookies, so after visiting `example.com/` the session is started and cookies are returned. The request to `/page` may be dependent on this session/cookies being set (but this would be WordPress, not `.htaccess`).

Comment: So, what I've narrowed the issue down to is that there is a problem with Wordpress not adding the trailing slash to the end of the directory. If you add it manually, it works.

Comment: Ah, you never included a trailing slash on the end of the URL-path (directory) in your question - even for the URL that appeared to work? You mentioned a trailing slash on the hostname - but the trailing slash is _always_ present after the hostname, even though the browser doesn't show this in the address bar. If the missing trailing slash on the end of the URL-path is the problem then this can be added with mod_rewrite in `.htaccess`. (Although I'm not sure whether this is something that WordPress can be forced to do?)

Comment: Yes, it's a problem only on the subdirectories. When I load them with the trailing slash (e.g. /page/), it works; when I load it in the menu, it loads with trailing slash. When I just type without the trailing slash, I'd assume .htaccess would find the page and send me over with a rewrite to a dash at the end. 

I've read it's better to have the trailing slash at the end hardcoded, because it can speed up the broswer. 

So, I just need to know how to modify it to add it.

Comment: bump - .htaccess is above.

Answer (score 0):

> When I load them with the trailing slash (e.g. `/page/`), it works; when I load it in the menu, it loads with trailing slash. When I just type without the trailing slash, [it doesn't work].

You missed the trailing slash in your question, so that made this question harder to fathom.

To force a trailing slash on all WordPress URLs you can try adding the following directive immediately *before* the WordPress front-controller.

```
RewriteRule !./$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=302,L]
```

Note that this is 302 (temporary) redirect. Only change it to a 301 (permanent) redirect when you are sure it's working OK. 301s are cached hard by the browser so can make testing problematic.

This should go here:

```
# Prevent further processing for existing files/directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# >>> HERE <<<

# Front controller
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

If you only need to apply to a specific host then added a condition to check this. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule !./$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=302,L]
```

> I've read it's better to have the trailing slash at the end hardcoded, because it can speed up the broswer.

This only applies to *physical directories*, not WordPress URLs. For WP URLs (or any other kind of *virtual* URL), it makes no difference, it's just personal preference. (FWIW, I prefer not to have the trailing slash, unless linking directly to a filesystem directory.)

For physical directories, Apache (mod_dir) will issue a 301 redirect to append the trailing slash. This is necessary, in order to be able to serve the directory index (eg. `index.php`) from that directory. So, in order to avoid the additional redirect, you should link to directories with a trailing slash.

Comment: Though I didn't mention it specifically (13 days ago), you're the first person that mentioned anything. You understand what I meant by the entire statement.

Next, I do not prefer to have the trailing slash, but I do prefer to have it now because if not the page will not load properly.

What do you mean about physical URLs versus WordPress? wp-login.php is a physical file in a physical directory on a physical server; no?

With regards to the modification, it seems to be working now; will continue to test.

Comment: "What do you mean about physical URLs versus WordPress?" - That's physical _directories_. In other words, URLs that map to physical directories on the filesystem. WordPress URLs (to pages) are entirely virtual - they don't map to a physical directory path. Only when a URL maps to a physical directory path _must_ you include the trailing slash (to "speed up the browser"). "wp-login.php is a physical file in a physical directory on a physical server; no?" Yes. But a WordPress URL like `/2017/10/17/some-page-slug` is not.

Comment: My apologies. I see database writes as physical writes on the disk as well, but I can understand what you're talking about.

I added the lines that you were suggesting to the .htaccess, and it appeared to work, at least once. However, it isn't working now.

How to apply this fix to virtual/Wordpress pages? I thought it could be in the way the URL is formatted in the database, but then the pages wouldn't load at all, most likely; no?